# Is XOR a pseudo command in MIPS?

Tags: assembly, mips

I'm not sure if XOR is a real command or if it is a psuedo command

Comment: This was a pretty trivial search, plus the assembler ref cards note which are pseudo.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is a [real instruction](http://www.mrc.uidaho.edu/mrc/people/jff/digital/MIPSir.html).